# Net::FTP::Recursive perl

Tags: perl, recursion, ftp

I am trying to retrieve contents of a directory from a FTP server using Net::FTP::Recursive module's rget function. When the remote directory has zip files, rget is not able to retrieve them, it does not throw any error. 
I am able to list all the zip files on remote directory just before calling rget too.

Is there a different way to handle zip files using rget?

Pseudo code:

```
my $ftp = Net::FTP::Recursive->new('host name');
$ftp->login('username', 'password');
$ftp->cwd('dir');
$ftp->rget();
```

on a different note, is there a way to specify directory name to rget function.

I appreciate your help!

Thanks,
NA

Comment: I don't see why it would treat zip files any differently to any other files. They are, after all, just files... If you ftp manually and try to get the zip files does that work?

Comment: Yes, I am able to retrieve them manually.

Comment: Perhaps turning on debug will help illuminate the problem? my $ftp = Net::FTP::Recursive->new('host name', 'Debug' => 1);